# Where should I ask a question about phones, not pertaining to a specific OS?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

If it were regarding iOS or Android, the answer would be simple. But what about phones in general?

The question in question is about whether one should remove a phone's battery when not in use.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there *is* a site where that question would be on-topic. It *may* have been on-topic at the dearly-departed [Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) site, but that site was pruned long ago.

<del>It *might* be okay at [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/), but I'm dubious. Read the [Help Center](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help) *very* carefully.</del>

Comment: So off to Area 51, huh? Thanks.

Comment: EE is a no go...

Comment: I'm rather shocked gadgets never made it. Or that no one knew it existed

Comment: Check super user.

Comment: @Braiam: Other folks with more familiarity with [su] have already said that that's not a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), but their help center explicitly says no, so that is not good. [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) the same.

There was a proposal to have a site for [Electronic Gadgets](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets), but it failed. There is not a site where the question is very much on-topic. You might have luck from a [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com) point-of-view, but that would require some source stating it is good or bad and you want to know if it is right or not:

> it is for researching the evidence behind claims you encounter. It is not for speculation, philosophical discussions or investigating original claims

Comment: Definately not on topic for us. Though if it was a laptop...

Comment: I know. The help center is very clear. MSU pointed to the Gadgets proposal which failed indeed. @JourneymanGeek

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. This question has [already been asked at Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5559/should-we-remove-batteries-from-electronic-devices-when-not-in-use), so that'd be a site for it.
2. It is unlikely that that question would be well-received on *any* site at the current point in time. That 2011 Skeptics question was in the first few [Google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=should+one+remove+a+phones+battery+when+not+in+use), it only took a few seconds to find (plus all the other info that exists about that topic), and some amount of research effort is generally expected.

In general, btw, searching for what you're looking for is often quicker than the process of forming a new question about it, for example comparing the above Google search with the process of [asking on SU and having it deleted](https://superuser.com/questions/1205270/remove-battery-from-phone-when-not-in-use), then asking where to ask here on MSE, then waiting for results, then asking on a different site, then waiting for results again (and most of those results would likely be as equally credible as Google results anyways, or based on the answerer doing that same research while writing).